# NTLM Kerberos support for Identity server which set behind nginx server (not working for IE)

Tags: docker, nginx, azure-active-directory, identityserver4, kerberos-delegation

I have Identity server 4 which reside behind ngnix proxy. and it support Azure AD.  now if I SSO on https then it is not working for IE browser but work properly in other browser due to IWA/NTLM/Kerberos .

So change need to do in ngnix to support that.

Comment: What is the issue here? Is it that it doesn't work with IE or is there something missing? Because you say that it's working in other browsers, so it seems like your auth backend setup is working properly.

Comment: This was due to http2 setting in. Nginx.

Comment: If you could please provide your answer in the answer section, that would be beneficial for future readers who might experience a NGINX issue similar to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have  default setting in nginx like this :

```
   listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
   listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
```

Then I have removed  http2

```
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
```

so IE has issue with SSL + http2